# How can I generate ion-option from an array with the value being array's item's index?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Here is the settings.html and settings.ts files' relevant code.

```js
export class SettingsPage {
  public teamA = [
    'Baner Team 1',
    'Baner Team 2',
    'Baner Team 3',
    'Baner Team 4',
    'Kothrud Team 1',
    'Kothrud Team 2',
    'Kothrud Team 3'
  ]

  public teamB = [
    'Baner Team 1',
    'Baner Team 2',
    'Baner Team 3',
    'Baner Team 4',
    'Kothrud Team 1',
    'Kothrud Team 2',
    'Kothrud Team 3'
  ]

  public SelectA;
  public SelectB;
}
```

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Team A</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectA">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let team of teamA; let i = index" value=" {{ i }} "> {{ team }} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  <br>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Team B</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectB">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of teamB; let z = index" value=" {{ z }} "> {{ item }} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<br>
<br>
<ion-item>
  <h1>Team A: {{ SelectA }}</h1>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <h1>Team B: {{ SelectB }}</h1>
</ion-item>
```

I want to generate the options from the arrays and the value from the array's index number. So suppose first option is selected, then the value for that particular ion-option will be its index i.e. 0.

PS: I have removed the ionic default imports, constructor etc. Just the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing `[value]="i"`. If you are assigning a variable to any html element, then it has to be in a angular way `[value]`

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectB">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of teamB; let z = index" [value]="z"> {{ item }} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-demo)

Comment: The list of the items from the array doesn't render. There are no options to choose from.

Comment: @DEDSEC_588 I have added a small demo. You may check that

Comment: Yes. The demo did not seem to work. I found a different fix. The real mistake I made was...declaring the array in export directly. Using this keyword and doing the same thing inside the constructor solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a minor syntax problem.

Can you try wrap the value in square brackets like so:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Team A</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectA">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let team of teamA; let i = index" [value]="i"> {{ team }} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  <br>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Team B</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="SelectB">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of teamB; let z = index" [value]="z"> {{ item }} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<br>
<br>
<ion-item>
  <h1>Team A: {{ SelectA }}</h1>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <h1>Team B: {{ SelectB }}</h1>
</ion-item>
```